# Replace string with new line + string in a big file

Tags: terminal, unix

I need to replace the string `),(` with `)\n,(` in a 10GB file. The \n in this case obviously stands for a newline.
I've tried so with this command:

```
sed -i '' '/),(/ s//),\n(/g' bigfile.sql
```

However, that didn't really work as expected. It did replace the string, but it didn't insert a newline, but simply a "n" (so it just neglected the backslash and escaped it).
Any other takes on this, or where's my mistake in the above command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
sed -i '' $'/),(/ s//),\\\n(/g' bigfile.sql
```

- `$'...'` indicates that the string is a C-style string. This allows you to use the `\\` and `\n` escapes, among others.
- In place of your `\n`, we have a `\\` and then a `\n`. This passes a literal backslash, and then a literal newline, to `sed`. This allows it to recognize that the newline is a part of the pattern, instead of terminating it.

The following also works:

```
sed -i '' '/),(/ s//),\
(/g' bigfile.sql
```